# What does this program do?

Tags: python

This is a simple program but I am finding difficulty how it is actually working.
I have  [database](https://hightailspaces.com/space/eFnpp/fi-75aa7eee-6224-492e-bddb-41f74b94bd3e/data.rar) with 3 tuples.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

queries = {}
rewrites = {}
urls = {}


for line in open("data.tsv"):
    q, r, u = line.strip().split("\t")

    queries.setdefault(q,0)
    queries[q] += 1
    rewrites.setdefault(r,0)
    rewrites[r] += 1
    urls.setdefault(u,0)
    urls[u] += 1

sQueries = []
sQueries = [x for x in rewrites.values()]
sQueries.sort()

x = range(len(sQueries))
line, = plt.plot(x, sQueries, '-' ,linewidth=2)
plt.show()
```

This is whole program,
Now

```
queries.setdefault(q,0)
```

This command will set the values as 0 , if key i,e and q is not found.

```
queries[q] += 1
```

This command will increment the value of each key by 1 if key is there. 
Same we continue with all tuples.
Then,

```
 sQueries = [x for x in rewrites.values()]
```

Then we store the values from Dictionary rewrites , to List Squeries

`x = range(len(sQueries))`

This command I am not getting what is happening. Can anyone please explain.

Comment: Have you tried looking up the documentation for the `range` and `len` functions?

Comment: Yes I know what range and len do.

Comment: [range](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range), [len](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#rang)

Comment: If you know what `range` and `len` do, how is `x = range(len(sQueries))` unclear?

Comment: Yes you are right, I was not getting how it was able to achieve that value with that database. Maybe I framed the wrong question. I think question doesn't have merit.Should I delete it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
sQueries = []
sQueries = [x for x in rewrites.values()]
sQueries.sort()
```

is an obtuse way of writing

```
 sQueries = rewrites.values()
 sQueries = sorted(sQueries)
```

in other words, sort the *values* of the `rewrites` dictionary. If, for the sake of argument, `sQueries == [2, 3, 7, 9]`, then `len(sQueries) == 4` and `range(4) == [0, 1, 2, 3]`.

So, now you're plotting `(0,2), (1,3), (2,7), (3,9)`, which doesn't seem very useful to me. It seems more likely that you would want the *keys* of `rewrites` on the x-axis, which would be the distinct values of `r` that you read from the TSV file.

Comment: Or just `sQueries = sorted(rewrites.values())`!

Comment: This answer is correct for Python 2, but in Python 3 `range(4)` is a `range` object, not a `list`. It would've been nice to see that specified in the question, I guess.

Answer (score 3):

```
len(sQueries)
```

gives number of elements in your list sQueries

```
x = range(len(sQueries))
```

will create a list x containing elements from 0,1,... to (but not including) length of your sQueries array

Comment: Perhaps worth stressing that it's 0,1,... upto but not including the length of sQueries.

Answer (score 2):

```
length = len(sQueries)  # this is length of sQueries
r = range(length)  # this one means from 0 to length-1
```

so

```
x = range(len(sQueries))  # means x is from 0 to sQueries length - 1
```